# UBUNTU touch DUALBOOT dualboot.sh install problem

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, ubuntu-for-android

I'd like to install ubuntu touch to my nexus 7 (2012) but I can't because dualboot.sh won't be install.

this is in my terminal

```
marci@marci-desktop:~$ chmod +x dualboot.sh
marci@marci-desktop:~$ ./dualboot.sh FULL
Using passed device id: FULL
Waiting for device FULL to install Ubuntu installer to.
error: device not found
error: device not found
Connected device is not supported
```

but my device is connected

```
marci@marci-desktop:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
015d257858642010    device
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called MultiRom available in the Google Play Store. It supports dual booting Nexus devices.

In order to use it, your device must be rooted. You will also need to install a custom recovery and kernel (both of which the app above will provide). One of the advantages of MultiRom is you can install multiple ROMs of any OS, including FirefoxOS, Ubuntu, and other Android ROMs.

[Here is the link to MultiRom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tassadar.multirommgr)

Answer (score 0):

I found this happened to me because I touched my screen by accident that disallowed my PC communicating with my device in debug mode.  To get around this I `revoke USB debugging authorizations` in the setting on my Nexus 4.  Then on my PC I restarted my adb server

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Then I ran the script again and added the security authorization